# pdflatex.exe: Invalid argument

Tags: beamer, pdftex

I'm creating a (rather large) Beamer file. When I try to compile, I receive this error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)

...

[31]pdflatex.exe: Invalid argument: myguide.vrb
pdflatex.exe: Data: myguide.vrb
texify: pdflatex.exe failed for some reason (see log file).
```

It previously compiled when I worked on it a few months ago, and I have no problems with any other document.

It stops and fails at a (seemingly) random slide each time, so it can't be an issue with the code itself. The .vrb file does exist in the same folder, so that can't be the issue, either. I've tried saving it under a different name, or deleting all the supplementary files before compiling, and none of that works.

I tried searching the error, but unfortunately it's so generic-looking that I didn't find any relevant solutions. Does anybody have any suggestions?

EDIT: Some commenters had asked for the log. Here it is, with the middle cut out:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.6.9)  24 NOV 2014 18:34
entering extended mode
**myguide.tex
("C:\Users\Me\myguide.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>      

...

]
("C:\Users\Me\myguide.toc") [29

]
("C:\Users\Me\myguide.vrb") [30

]
("C:\Users\Me\myguide.vrb") [31

]
```

The log essentially just cuts off here.

Comment: `see log file`? Welcome to TeX SE!

Comment: What @cfr means is that it would *really* help if you can post the error you receive along with (if at all possible) a minimal document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Run it with admin rights or delete the .aux file and recompile from scratch?

Comment: Try to compile with pdflatex directly instead using texify.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the suggestions. The above is the error I receive, I didn't receive any other error? It also doesn't pin down any particular line or part of my code (which is extremely long), so I'm not sure if sharing it would help. @percusse, Ulrike Fischer: I tried all of those things to no avail (I even tried them together!). I also updated from WinEdt 8.1 to 9, which hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: Do you get the same error without `texify`? Also, the log is not going to tell us much with only what you've included here. At least, that's my guess. I don't use this system so others might see something I would be oblivious to ;).

Comment: Can you successfully compile a simple document e.g. `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}hello\end{document}`? If so, we need an MWE as mentioned above. If not, try without texify. If you still get the error, we probably need more info from that log. What are you doing with `myguide.vrb`? Are you using it twice? To do what? (Doesn't Windows do something odd with open files like not let anything else access them? Or am I imagining that? I could well be.)

Comment: I'm using a lot of [fragile] frames, because, ironically, I'm writing a guide for early beginners starting out in LaTeX. :) That's where the .vrb comes in. I can compile other documents with no issue. Is it possible to overload pdflatex.exe with too many fragile frames?

Comment: It is not so easy to create a loop of frames but by outsourcing it to an external file I could create a beamer file with 600 fragile frames without problems. Your system doesn't look up-to-date so check for updates (as user *and* as admin). You could also try debugview (http://www.miktex.org/diagnosing). But beside this: without the means to reproduce the problem it is difficult to help.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error, and it is because of Windows 8.1 feature "smart files". These are files that you can see in windows explorer, and they apparently exists in your hard drive, but their content is online, possibly on your onedrive account. When I made sure my file was available offline, then I was able to compile my latex. In windows explorer, right click your myguide.vrb file and make it available offline

Comment: How does it become "online" in the first place?

Comment: Be wary of any windows notion that begins with the word "smart".

Comment: It can become "online" if you are keeping it in OneDrive so it will be synced across multiple machines.